# CVS showing all files as outgoing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I recently switched my development workstation from Windows to Linux (Fedora64). I use Eclipse with PDT and CVS for PHP programming. I copied my entire project folder, including the .project file to my Linux system and imported it in Eclipse. It automatically detected the CVS server IP and login. However, when I sync, it shows all my files (>8000) as outgoing, and moreover the sync is always stuck at 79%. How do I fix this without checking out the entire project from CVS again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with timestamps that are now slightly out-of-sync with the meta data recorded in the hidden ./CVS folders of your working copy. Try running `cvs status` on your sandbox (sorry, I'm not familiar with Eclipse's CVS interface, but that's how you would do it on the command line). That should reset the supposedly modified files.

You also might get away with simply running Update. If all else fails, do a fresh Checkout.

**Update:** I googled a little and found some articles that can be interpreted to say that Eclipse does an implicit `status` when doing an "Update" or "Update Check".

Comment: This seems like a good idea, only problem is I have no idea how to execute that command on Eclipse! Can someone else help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work. It tells me - "The server reported an error while performing the "cvs update" command." :(

Comment: @Atriya: Hmm, does it also tell you what error the server reported?

Comment: @OliverGiesen You made my day, thanks! Whatever eclipse does, it somehow confuses command line CVS, so I was getting "no repository, here, do checkout first" message. Doing cvs status first takes care of this. I use command-line cvs to check in, because eclipse wants to add all new files (does anyone know how to tell eclipse to stop adding new files without explicit add?).